# pointer to methods in C# delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

In the following code, does `ptrcall` point...

- to 2 places on the heap with methods `obj.callMe` and `obj1.callMe`; or...
- to 1 place that contains both methods `obj.callMe`, `obj1.callMe` within it?

  ```
  public delegate void CallEveryOne();

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  public CallEveryOne ptrcall=null;

  public Form2 obj = new Form2();
  public Form3 obj1 = new Form3();

      obj.Show();
      obj1.Show();

      ptrcall += obj.CallMe;
      ptrcall += obj1.CallMe;
  }
  ```

Comment: Make sense this question does not.

Comment: My babblefish just died.

Comment: @Mehdi, I edited your question quite a bit in an attempt to make it more legible and understandable. Please verify that it still asks the question that you intended to ask. If not, feel free to perform a rollback to your original.

Comment: @Mehdi, your latest edits have resulted in broken code (and horrible indentation). You cannot declare `public` fields inside a class method. Also, you cannot refer to the local variable `ptrcall` (defined in `Form1_Load`) in another method (`button1_Click`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptrcall` is, like basically all delegates from .NET 2.0 onward, a multicast delegate. That is, it keeps its own internal list of methods that it refers to. MSDN has the following to say on `MulticastDelegate`:

> *Represents a multicast delegate; that is, a delegate that can have more than one element **in its invocation list**.* (Emphasis added by me.)

So, in your terminology, the answer is most likely that `ptrcall` point to 2 place on heap.

But why does this implementation detail matter at all?

---

**P.S.:** You could call `ptrcall.GetInvocationList()` and see what you get back. I only recommend this to you for toying around and getting to know delegates better; don't do it in production code unless you really *have to*.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what your code does, and what `MulticastDelegate`s offer. If you call the delegate, *both* `obj.CallMe` and `obj1.CallMe` will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to know this for interop with unmanaged coe? Ptrcall stores reference to instance of object of type CallEveryOne (that derives from type MulticastDelegate). This object contains (among other things) internal array with information about each method added to this delegate, but you are not intended to use it directly. If you need pointers to subscribed methods, use ptrcall.GetInvocationList() to get list of methods and System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() to convert them to pointers.

Comment: Your answer is basically correct, @Nuf. But I find your use of terminology such as _"ptrcall points to …"_ problematic. `ptrcall` is **not** a *pointer*! I feel that people who are fairly new to .NET or C# should be encouraged to get familiar with the basics of value and reference types as early as possible and stop thinking in terms of implementation details (@Mehdi's use of the term _"heap"_ comes to mind here; so does the concept of pointers, which are rarely used in C#). See e.g. [these blog posts by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/memory+management/).

Comment: @stakx: Sure, ptrcall is **not** pointer, it is variable that holds **reference** to object. I don't thing, that word "points" implies ptrcall beeing a pointer (which is not), but still I modified my answer to (hopefully) prevent any confusion.